# Can't Delete Behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having trouble with something that should be patently obvious. I cant seem to be able to delete properties of my object in node. This is in coffeescript, but I don't think that is relevant.

```
console.log doc
delete doc.password
console.log doc
```

Returns:

```
{ firstname: 'Andrew',
  lastname: 'Plummer',
  email: 'andrew@stackoverflow...',
  password: 'blahblah',
  _id: 5014c0a6af36bdaf03000001,
  comments: [],
  posts: [] }

{ firstname: 'Andrew',
  lastname: 'Plummer',
  email: 'andrew@stackoverflow...',
  password: 'blahblah',
  _id: 5014c0a6af36bdaf03000001,
  comments: [],
  posts: [] }
```

For something so seemingly obvious I have actually searched around stackoverflow and googled for about half an hour. Sorry if still i have missed a duplicate.

Comment: Would you show the output of: `(function(){doc={firstname:"Andrew",lastname:"Plummer",email:"andrew@stackoverflow...",password:"blahblah",_id:"5014c0a6af36bdaf03000001",comments:[],posts:[]},console.log("before deletion: "+doc.password),delete doc.password,console.log("after deletion: "+doc.password)})()`

Comment: @Andrew, the `password` property might have been defined through a call to [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), with the `configurable` descriptor field omitted (or explicitly set to `false`). In that case, not being able to `delete` that property would be by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer as given by Frédéric in the comment ( so i cant mark it as true) is that my object needed to be explicitly turned into a new object as it had its delete disabled. This is the case with mongoose ODM models in node.